# Interleave a list with itself and another list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of 6 numbers and I have a list containing 4 lists.  I want to put the first 3 numbers in the first list and the next 2 numbers in the list after it and  finally the last number in the list of 6 in the last list of lists.
I know this is confusing but here is my code to visualize it :

```
Start_Comparing_Index = -1
Looping_Counter = 4 # = 4
for counter in range(4):
Looping_Counter -= 1  # =3
Start_Comparing_Index += 1  # = 0
print("counter = " + str(counter))
for i in range(Looping_Counter):
    s[counter].append(x[Start_Comparing_Index])
    print("Comp index= " + str(Start_Comparing_Index))
    if i == range(Looping_Counter)[-1]:
        break
    else:
        Start_Comparing_Index += 1
print(s) 


but its printing out :

counter = 0
Comp index= 0
Comp index= 1
Comp index= 2
counter = 1
Comp index= 3
Comp index= 4
counter = 2
Comp index= 5
counter = 3
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

Although I want it to print this list instead:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]]
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: sorry the title doesn't have anything to do with the code and x =[1,2,3,4,5,6] and s = [[]]*4

Comment: Edited the title since you yourself commented that it hasn't anything to do with the question body (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_lists(src, n):
    r, s = [], 0
    for i in range(n, -1, -1):
        r.append(src[s:s+i])
        s += i
    return r

print(get_lists(list(range(1, 7)), 3))
# [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], []]
```

Comment: Yo Ferhat I think that have solved my problem and what I wanted.
I'll edit that code to satisfy my exact needs thank you very much & help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Strange question.  If you know exactly the length of all lists, and the exact mix of elements you want in the result, why don't you exactly write that, without any loops?

```
>>> first = range(1,7)
>>> second = [6]
>>> merged = [first[0:3], first[3:-1], second]
>>> merged
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
```

Comment: Because I want it to be a generic code because sometimes I don't want to take just the 3 elements but want to take 4 or 5 depending on a certain variable I can extract from a data the user inputs.

Comment: Then your question should state those conditions.

Comment: sorry man it's my first time on here didn't know next time i'll be sure to add it.
Thanks for your efforts to help me,appreciated :)